# Apache server displays just a white screen, but is running

Tags: php, apache

I am using apache2 + php5 for my server to develop a local site.

But all I get when attempting to visit localhost, or localhost/index.php is a blank screen.

The server is running (ping test and check of daemons proves that), and when I try to visit a non-existent page, I get the correct 404 message.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: did you have a look at the logfiles?

Comment: Post the contents of `localhost/index.php`. It could just be an empty file?

Comment: I had a look at log files; they don't say anything about it. index.php is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your `index.php` put the following so you can see your bug

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 0):

When php encounters a fatal error, e.g a missing ; or extra ' it error, if error reporting is off, you'll just see a white screen. try replacing index.php with `<?php var_dump($_SERVER); ?>` as a test to see if the problem is a php error or if it's Apache itself.